# grid image responsive and without padding

Tags: html, image, web, responsive-design

I need to "build" an image that is composed of different pieces.
Here a schema:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtOPI.jpg

There is no space or padding between each piece of the image, and it would be nice if the entire image was responsive...any idea? 
I tried this, but the image loses responsivity:

```
     echo '<div id="top_testa" style="overflow: hidden; ">
     <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 
    20%;max-height: 20%;" >

          </div>
      <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-right:8.5%;max-width: 
   20%;max-height: 20%;" >
   <img 
 src="TestaLuc.png" id="top_head" name="top_head">
  </div>

  <div class="image-div" style="float:left;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;">

  </div>


  <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>';
echo '<div id="base_testa" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >

  </div>
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-right:8.5%;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >
   <img src="BaseTestaMim.png" id="bottom_head" name="bottom_head">
  </div>

  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;">

  </div>


  <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>';
echo '<div id="asta" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >

  </div>
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-right:8.6%;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >
   <img src="AstSupNull.png" id="top_asta" name="top_asta">
  </div>

  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;">

  </div>


  <div style="clear:right;"></div>
</div>';

echo '<div id="middle" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-left:0px;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >

  </div>
  <div class="image-div" style="float:right;margin-right:13.3%;max-width: 20%;max-height: 20%;" >
   <img src="AstInfLuc.png" id="bottom_left_asta" name="bottom_left_asta" align="right">
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: About your code: close the PHP markup before writing all that HTML, your code would be easier to read. And indent your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `no-gutters` class for your Bootstrap rows to remove padding and the `img-fluid` class for your images to make them responsive.

Here's a working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/animals" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/arch" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/tech" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/nature" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/940/400/people" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placeimg.com/1240/200/any" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "col-4" not work, "col-md-4" works, and "no-gutter" not work. What version of bootstrap i need?

Comment: The same version as the tag you used for this question and the same as the css linked in my snippet.

Comment: Ok, but if i couldn't use bootstrap 4?

Comment: Then I'm gonna delete my answer.

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the responsive with the 100% width tag

```
<img src="img.jpg" width="100%">
```